# when I insert a value to database it inserted two rows to database

Tags: php, mysql

In Android app I use Php code for insert data to sql database
when I inserting one record to data base, it is inserting two records . Here is

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "...";
$mysql_user     = "...";
$mysql_password = "...";

$con            = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database) || die("Error DB Connect");

$selectedDb     = mysql_select_db($mysql_database)||  die("Error in opening DB");

$points =  $_POST["points"];
$user   =  $_POST["user"];

$sql    =  "INSERT INTO `cusTrans`( `CID`, `Point`, `Date`, `time`,`Description`)
            VALUES ($user,$points,CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIME,'Claim Point')";

if (mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Fault".mysql_error();
}
?>
```

**Android:**

```
httpclientCD     =  new DefaultHttpClient();
httppostCD       =  new HttpPost("http://.../ClaimRecord.php");      
nameValuePairsCD =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairsCD.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", cus_id1));
nameValuePairsCD.add(new BasicNameValuePair("points", "1"));
httppostCD.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairsCD));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
responseCD = httpclientCD.execute(httppostCD);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
final String response1 = httpclientCD.execute(httppostCD, responseHandler);
System.out.println("Response CusUpdatePOint : "+id+"--" + response1);
```

Comment: First check if request is sending more than one time ??

Comment: You are still using mysql_*. Please stop and use PDO/mysqli instead.

Comment: I think your question is belong to php not android.

Comment: You get same records twice?? @Sajith  mysql_ is deprecated, so you have to move to mysqli or PDO. Other than that, the php looks fine. its only single entry.

Comment: put a write to a text file log before that call to the php. See if you are calling it twice instead of assuming a mysql issue.

Comment: I guess you're experiencing CORS. The first request is an OPTIONS request and the second one the real POST request. Could you add some logging with `error_log` and check the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try commenting out the line that starts with ResponseCD in your android part?
Sorry for the short answer but i'm on my mobile.

Comment: You were doing the .execute twice, hence the problem. Glad it helped!